# A question about the Andrica's conjecture on the prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The Andrica's conjecture on the prime numbers states:
given a couple of prime numbers $p_k$ and $p_{k+1}$ the following inequality holds:
$$\sqrt{p_{k+1}}-\sqrt{p_{k}}\lt 1$$
Is it possible to show that the following inequality holds?
$$\sqrt{p_{k+n}}-\sqrt{p_{k}}\lt \frac{1}{n}$$
for $k$ enough large and $n\in N$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you mean that $p_k$ and $p_{k+1}$ are consecutive prime numbers? And similarly that $p_{k+n}$ is the $n$-th prime after $p_k$?

Comment: Yes. I mean exactly this.

Comment: Since $\sqrt{p_{k+n}} - \sqrt{p_k} > \sqrt{p_{k+1}} - \sqrt{p_k}$, it already seems dubious to conjecture $\sqrt{p_{k+n}} - \sqrt{p_k} < 1$, let alone $\sqrt{p_{k+n}} - \sqrt{p_k} < \frac{1}{n}$. Is this really what you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Original solution (to the wrong question):

By the prime number theorem, $p_k\approx k\ln k$ and $p_{k+n}\approx (k+n)\ln(k+n)$ so your LHS is $\approx \sqrt{(k+n)\ln(k+n)}-\sqrt{k\ln k}=\frac{(k+n)\ln (k+n)-k\ln k}{\sqrt{(k+n)\ln(k+n)}+\sqrt{k\ln k}}$.  As $n\rightarrow \infty$, this diverges as $\sqrt{n\ln n}$.

Updated solution:

Suppose this were true, for any particular $n$.  Then $$\sqrt{p_{k+1}}-\sqrt{p_k}\le \sqrt{p_{k+n}}-\sqrt{p_k}<\frac{1}{n}<1$$

Hence, this would imply a stronger version of Andrica's conjecture.  I doubt you will find an answer on Math.SE.

Comment: I have $k \to \infty$, not $n \to \infty$

Comment: In that case this appears to be a direct generalization of Andrica's conjecture.  Do you have evidence in support?

Comment: Only numerical calculation for $k\le 10^8$ and $n\le 10$

Comment: @Riccardo.Alestra Maximal prime gaps is an area where our strongest upper bounds are not even remotely close to empirical observation.  We believe that as $k \to \infty$, $\sqrt{p_{k_n}} - \sqrt{p_k} \ll_n k^{-1/2}(\log k)^{3/2} \to 0$, but the best known upper bound is $k^c$ for some *positive* $c$ (with a multiplicative constant depending on $n$).

Answer (score 0):

Let $n/2 > k$ then
$\sqrt{p_{k+n}}-\sqrt{p_{k}}\lt \frac{1}{n}$ is equivilent to

$$\sqrt{p_{3k}}-\sqrt{p_{k}}\lt \frac{1}{2k}$$

But, the prime $p_{3k} > 2p_k$ (For proof see  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_prime)

This means $\sqrt{p_{3k}} > \sqrt{2}\sqrt{p_{k}}$ So,

$\sqrt{2}\sqrt{p_{k}} - \sqrt{p_{k}} = (\sqrt{2}-1)\sqrt{p_{k}}$

Now, for $k > 4$ we see failure. Sorry, QED.

Comment: You can't let $n=2k$ since $k$ is arbitrarily large based on the choice of $n$.

Comment: Ok, let n/2 > k. Still fails.

Comment: You can't do that. $k$ is _arbitrarily_ large based on $n$. The OP can require $k>10^{1000}$ when $n=2$, $k>10^{10^{1000}}$ when $n=3$, etc. if (s)he wants to.

Comment: @Charles With $k > 4$, that is "enough large" that with $n > 2*k$ it fails. It is all in how you read it.

Comment: $n>2k$ can be assumed to _never_ hold in this problem. In fact, for any $\alpha>0,$ you can assume that $n<\alpha k.$

Comment: And, here is the magic word "assumed". I already stated what was assumed on my part, and you are arguing a mute point. I still read it the way that I did, what I said does hold to the statements stated. I think you are reading more into the question than me.

Comment: What you wrote doesn't answer the question because you assume that $k$ is small in direct contradiction to the text.

Comment: No, if $k>10^{10^{1000}}$ and $n > 2k$ it still fails.

Comment: It seems you still don't understand the problem. Let's make it more explicit. You can suppose (as a weaker version of the requirement in the question) that $k>10^n$. Then you $n>2k$ is never true.

Comment: But you are assuming something that was not stated. Nothing was stated about $n > k$ or $ k > n$. We can assume anything, and what I thought about was what I stated above. Sorry you don't like it, but the failure, it still holds. If you feel that can answer the question better, I would suggest that you point out both sides of this as you answer it yourself.

Comment: This is exactly what "for $k$ large enough" means. For any $n$ it's OK to have the inequality fail for finitely many $k$. So it doesn't help _at all_ to show that it fails for $k=1,2,\ldots,\lfloor n/2\rfloor$ because we're only asked to show that it works for $k$ large enough. It's not a question of what I like or dislike -- you just haven't answered the question.